# How can i improve readability of my website on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The homepage/index.html seems fair enough to launch as-is for the time being. But when I look at it from chrome on mobile, all the lettering is too small - particularly in the navbar - and my parallax effect doesn't work on mobile either.

I tried making changes to the scale within the viewport, but I honestly just don't know what I'm doing. I would be so grateful if someone could possibly take a look at the website on mobile (and desktop too, if you'd like) and maybe make some suggestions on a quick cheap fix for making it more readable while maintaining its look of 'prettiness'. And if you know how to keep the parallax intact on mobile that would be amazing too!

Here are the links to the website, and to the code on github:

https://ido-weddingsandevents.herokuapp.com/index.html

https://github.com/if-true/i_do_weddings_and_events/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Have you considered using ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">``` instead of  ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280">```? You can then use media queries to adjust the font sizes according to the device width

Answer (score -1):

To make your navigation larger and your image titles on mobile you can try this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 860px){
.navigation li a {
    font-size: 80px;
}
.parallaxImage h2 {
    font-size: 56px;
    line-height: 94px;
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap you have to insert `<div class="row">...</div>` inside the `class="container"` . Better use a percentage in `.navigation { width: 100%; max-width: 500px; }` for mobile compatibility. Font-Awesome, PT Serif, and Delius Swash Caps are not used. Loading them is not good for performance.

If you are using @media, setup like this, **for example**

```
.navigation li a { font-size: 24px; }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navigation li a { font-size: 36px; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navigation li a { font-size: 60px; }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navigation li a { font-size: 72px; }
}
```

Important to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Why giving -1 for debugging this website? These bugs are the most important, and you'll have a good page after debugging all mentioned.